# JavaScript - Clicking on item and deleting it from the parent div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I got an parent div and child divs. JavaScript creates child divs, ID & the text inside is different.. So I am trying to do next. There will be X behind of each item and if you click it will remove the item, is that possible to do? I tried something with JavaScript, but I didn't understand how to do that part if you click on that item then it removes that. Also, it has to remove one class as well which contains same item name. I will put some code down below.

HTML Example:

```
<div id="itemcart" style="float: left;height: 184px;width: 330px;left: 245px;">
  <div id="★_Butterfly_Knife__Crimson_Web_Field-Tested">★ Butterfly Knife | Crimson Web (Field-Tested)</div>
  <div id="AWP__Asiimov_Battle-Scarred">AWP | Asiimov (Battle-Scarred)</div>
  <div id="AK-47__Wasteland_Rebel_Field-Tested">AK-47 | Wasteland Rebel (Field-Tested)</div>
  <div id="M4A1-S__Cyrex_Field-Tested">M4A1-S | Cyrex (Field-Tested)</div>
  <div id="AWP__Corticera_Minimal_Wear">AWP | Corticera (Minimal Wear)</div>
  <div id="StatTrak™_USP-S__Torque_Field-Tested">StatTrak™ USP-S | Torque (Field-Tested)</div>
  <div id="Chroma_2_Case">Chroma 2 Case</div>
  <div id="Chroma_2_Case">Chroma 2 Case</div>
  <div id="Chroma_2_Case">Chroma 2 Case</div>
  <div id="Souvenir_Nova__Walnut_Field-Tested">Souvenir Nova | Walnut (Field-Tested)</div>
  <div id="Galil_AR__Kami_Factory_New">Galil AR | Kami (Factory New)</div>
  <div id="Tec-9__Red_Quartz_Field-Tested">Tec-9 | Red Quartz (Field-Tested)</div>
  <div id="Chroma_2_Case">Chroma 2 Case</div>
  <div id="Chroma_2_Case">Chroma 2 Case</div>
  <div id="Chroma_2_Case">Chroma 2 Case</div>
  <div id="Chroma_2_Case">Chroma 2 Case</div>
  <div id="Chroma_2_Case">Chroma 2 Case</div>
  <div id="Chroma_2_Case">Chroma 2 Case</div>
</div>
```

Those div's which are under the itemcart, are added by JavaScript, by clicking "item-card". Item-card get's names from the picture title (image of item). If the item-card is clicked, then it adds class "item-selected". If the item will be deleted by clicking on it, then it should also remove that item-selected class from the right item on item card. Is something like that possible to do?

Comment: You could use `.remove()`. Note, there are duplicate `id`s at `html`

Comment: Yeah, then it should just use :last if it is duplicate.

Comment: Also, how could I use .remove() to remove that item from there?

Comment: There should not be duplicate `id`s in `document`

Comment: At the moment I got one system to delete, but I don't like it that way. I got it like, it will remove item from cart if you reclick on the item, but would be better if you could click on "X"

Comment: "*There will be X behind of each item*" Where is the code for this? How are the "x"es being added and how are they related to each child item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.append()` , `.parent()` , `.remove()`

```js
$("#itemcart div").each(function() {
  // append `span` having text `"X"` to each `div` in `#itemcart`
  $(this).append("<span> X</span>");      
});

$("#itemcart span").click(function() {
  // remove clicked `span` parent element
  $(this).parent().remove()
});
```

```css
#itemcart span {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="itemcart" style="float: left;height: 184px;width: 330px;left: 245px;">
  <div id="★_Butterfly_Knife__Crimson_Web_Field-Tested">★ Butterfly Knife | Crimson Web (Field-Tested)</div>
  <div id="AWP__Asiimov_Battle-Scarred">AWP | Asiimov (Battle-Scarred)</div>
  <div id="AK-47__Wasteland_Rebel_Field-Tested">AK-47 | Wasteland Rebel (Field-Tested)</div>
  <div id="M4A1-S__Cyrex_Field-Tested">M4A1-S | Cyrex (Field-Tested)</div>
  <div id="AWP__Corticera_Minimal_Wear">AWP | Corticera (Minimal Wear)</div>
  <div id="StatTrak™_USP-S__Torque_Field-Tested">StatTrak™ USP-S | Torque (Field-Tested)</div>
  <div id="Chroma_2_Case">Chroma 2 Case</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Wow, that was seriously so easy :O? Is there possibility to add that X behind the item name? :)

Comment: heh, if I tried append didn't wanted to delete other text for me

Comment: _"heh, if I tried append didn't wanted to delete other text for me "_ ? Try updated stacksnippets

Comment: Also, if I may ask. Is it possible to change that "each" for something different? Thing is, if I choose item from the "market" then for each item it adds that X for even that who has it already.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to change `.each()` . When item is selected, append `span` to corresponding `div`

Comment: Could you please make an "example" for me :)? I am not best in that sadly, "learning phase"

Comment: This is a good Question to learn from. You should put forth some effort into solving own Question.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5 you can declare custom attribute for the tags.
For example, if you are printing products you are going to do something similar:

```
<?php
    foreach($products as $p) {
        echo '<div class="single-product" data-product-id="' . $p->id. '" data-product-price="' . $p->price . '">' . $product->name . '</div>';
    }
?>
```

After that you can interact with single items with jQuery queries

```
$(".sincle-product[data-product-id=1]").function();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script then you have to add a class named 'removeItem' to your divs

//Jquery library

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        $( ".removeItem" ).click(function() {
            this.remove();
        });
    }
</script>
```